# How to load layers depending on zoom level?

Tags: openlayers

I want to control the zoom in OpenLayers.

When the zoom is 3 I want to load KML1 and when the zoom is 4 i want to load KML2.

Could you please advise me how I can control the zoom-event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a way to accomplish that is to register an event on event "zoomend" on your map with something like

```
map.events.register(type, obj, listener);
```

You can find more info there: http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html

Maybe you should also load both of your kml and then hide / show the correct layer depend on the zoom level.

Comment: I want that every change of the zoom to do something.Th event that I inserted is zoom_changed but it is not working.maybe you have the list of all the events

Answer (score 7):

As j_freyre mentioned you should register a function, which changes the visibility of your KML-layers, to the "zoomend"-event. In your case it has to look like this:

```js
map.events.register("zoomend", map, zoomChanged);

zoomChanged()
{
  zoom = map.getZoom();
  if (zoom == 3)
  {
    kml1.setVisibility (true);
    kml2.setVisibility (false);
  }
  else if (zoom == 4)
  {
    kml1.setVisibility (false);
    kml2.setVisibility (true);
  }
}
```

Comment: It's more efficient to store the `getZoom` value in a variable like `zoom = map.getZoom();` and then check it out on the if statements like `if (zoom == 3)`. In this way you're avoiding to call `getZoom` each time.